# URL assertion failing in playwright while implementing Page Object model

Tags: playwright, assertion, pageobjects

I am trying to implement POM in playwright, I have created a class in which I am trying to click two buttons to navigate to a page and then apply URL assertion to check the expected URL. But the URL of the Page isn't changing and the assertion is getting failed. here is the class code:

```
exports.HomePage = class HomePage {
 


constructor(page) {

    this.page = page
    this.login_button = page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Login' })
    this.client_login_button = page.getByRole(('link', { name: 'CLIENT LOGIN' }))
}

async gotoHomePage(){
    await this.page.goto('https://plentifulapp.com/');
    await this.login_button.click
    await this.client_login_button.click
}
```

}
and here is the main test file.

```
test.only('ValidLogin', async ({ page }) => {

const Home = new HomePage(page);

await Home.gotoHomePage();

await expect(page).toHaveURL('https://app.plentifulapp.com/a/pantries')
```

Asserting applied in main test file in getting failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the culprit is that the click methods aren’t actually being called, you’re just referencing the methods themselves. So the fix hopefully is just putting `()` after `.click` which should at least correct that and make sure the clicks are actually happening.